# Inject into asp.net web api model with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I want to use `IValidatableObject.Validate()` to check some aspects of my model against a repository before processing requests. However, with the config below `_dalForValidation` is never set in on `Models.App`, in other words the default empty constructor is always being called.

```
private static void ConfigureAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterType<DataAccessFacade>().As<IDataAccess>().InstancePerApiRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<Models.App>();
    var container = builder.Build();
    var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
}
```

`App` has 2 constructors:

```
public App(IDataAccess dalForValidation)
{
    _dalForValidation = dalForValidation;
}

public App() {}
```

for completeness this is where I try to access it, getting a null reference exception:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var existingApps = _dalForValidation.FindApps().Convert<DB.App,App>();
    if (!ValidateProxyMappings(existingApps))
        yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid proxy mapping");
}
```

Perhaps the dependency resolver is not used for the model, or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: What happens if you remove the scoping config on the DataAccessFacade registration?  Just for diagnosis purposes.

Comment: If the InstancePerApiRequest scoping is removed the situation remains exactly the same. As an aside the dal is being correctly inserted into the controllers.

Comment: Does the empty default constructor need to be preserved? Can you remove it and test without?

Comment: Other thoughts: is something happening in the course of `RegisterApiControllers` that could be causing this?  Does it work if you register the constuctor call explicitly (`builder.Register(c => new Models.App(c.Resolve<IDataAccess>()))`)?

Comment: @Mark I have created a separate solution to test your suggestons (i cannot remove the deault constructor in my app) with the following results: (1) removeing the default constructor causes the other constructor to be called with a null argument (2) explicitly registering the constructor has no effect.  when I combine this info with the fact that autofac should chose the constructor with the most parameters I can only conclude that ASP.net web api does not use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver when creating model classes.